# How to work with workspaces in TYPO3 7.6

Tags: typo3, workspace, typo3-7.6.x

How is it possible in version 7.6 of TYPO3 to add a second workspace? I was able to successfully activate the extension *workspace management* and there appears a menu entry *workspaces* in the menu bar but I could not find a possibility to add a second workspace. Furthermore there isn't a menu entry in the top menu bar how it used to be (atleast in version 6.1.5).

Is there a configuration step I overlooked? Was the workspace management concept revised in version 7.6? Is there documentation to this?

Regards,
Thomas

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a new workspace in the list view on your very root page (Pid 0). Just click *add record* scroll down to *workspace* and create as many workspaces as you need.

[image: Result of newly created workspace with title "Workspace"]

As for the top menu. There is a menu entry. After installing workspace extension, try reloading you backend once. It should appear next to the help menu entry.

[image: Workspace entries in top menu after reloading browser]

Comment: I activated the standard workspace extenstion (Workspaces Management, Key workspaces) but even after reloading / emptying the cache the menu entry doesn't appear in the top menu bar. Is there a need to install another extension?

Comment: @thomas No other extension is required, but you need to create a "Workspace" record in the root-page of your page-tree. See https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/workspaces/Administration/CustomWorkspace/Index.html for further details on the settings

Answer (score 1):

After you created the workspace and if it doesn't appear in the top menu bar you only need to log out and then log in again. After this it should appear next to the help menu entry. I tested it with TYPO3 CMS 8.1.2 and 7.6.9 and 6.2.25.